# GWT upgrade from 2.7.0. to 2.8.2 (or 2.8.1) not working

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am trying to upgrade my Eclipse (Mars 2, Mac) project that uses Google app engine and GWT to gwt version 2.8.2 but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.util.regexfilter.RegexFilter: method <init>()V not found
    at com.google.gwt.util.regexfilter.WhitelistRegexFilter.<init>(WhitelistRegexFilter.java:21)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JJSOptionsImpl.<init>(JJSOptionsImpl.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.PrecompileTaskOptionsImpl.<init>(PrecompileTaskOptionsImpl.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilerOptionsImpl.<init>(CompilerOptionsImpl.java:30)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:108)
```

I fount solutions to have my java compiler level and java facet to 1.8, but it's not working.

Also in my classpath i have :

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 8 [1.8.0_172]">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the gwt-servlet.jar file which was in the WebContent/lib folder, becuase it was from gwt-2.7.0. Although I tried different settings in Order and Export (java build path properties), the compiler did not work until I copied the gwt-servlet.jar file from gwt-2.8.1.

Answer (score 1):

That error could be a symptom of mixing different versions of GWT.  In the process of your upgrade from 2.7 to 2.8 you might have multiple versions of GWT jars on your path?

Comment: I do believe that could be an issue, but I tried to clear everything. I even renamed the folders that contain the other gwt versions si only the path to 2.8.2 can remain valid. But no luck

Comment: Are you using GPE Google Plugin for Eclipse?   Or the newer GWT Eclipse Plugin?  What version?

Comment: Could GWT's unit cache be corrupted?  Look for a directory called 'gwt-unitCache' or '.gwt-unitCache' and delete it to start fresh.